# JQuery Event on SVG not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, svg

I have a problem with events. I have a div, inside which I have an svg area. On that area I want to place some nodes in some groups. I need a different behaviour for when I click on an empty area and and a different one for when I click on the svg rectangle.

The thing is, only my div contextmenu event is firing. My JS:

```
$(function() {

$('#mainBoard').on("click", function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('body').append("DivEventTiggered ");
    return false;
});

$("svg").find("g.node").find("rect").on("click", function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('body').append("SVGEventTriggered");
    return false;
})

$('#add-svg').click(function (ev) {
        d3.select("#SVGcanvas")
        .append("g")
        .attr("id", "id0")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", 40)
        .attr("height", 40)
        .style("fill", "purple")
        .style("opacity", "0.1")
        .style("border", "1px black solid");
    return false;
})
})
```

CSS:

```
#mainBoard {
padding: 0;
margin: auto;
display: block;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
border: 1px solid black;
}

#menu {
height: 37px;
}
```

And my HTML snippet

```
<div id="mainBoard">
<svg id="SVGcanvas" style="height:inherit; width:inherit; display:block;"></svg>
<div id="menu">
    <button id="add-svg" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-right: 10px;">Add SVG</button>
</div>
```

Here you can see that only Div Event is triggered:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gvu9magq/5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are binding click event to svg rectangles before they exist (by clicking the add svg button).

The simplest solution would be:

```
$('#add-svg').click(function (ev) {
        d3.select("#SVGcanvas")
        .append("g")
        .attr("id", "id0")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", 40)
        .attr("height", 40)
        .style("fill", "purple")
        .style("opacity", "0.1")
        .style("border", "1px black solid");

         // now the g node exists
         $("svg").find("g.node").find("rect").on("click", function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            $('body').append("SVGEventTriggered");
            return false;
        })
    return false;
})
```

Comment: Cool! That works, I can't believe I didn't think about that, thanks!